# How to select a drop down list option in espresso webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-espresso

I have a list drop down in a webpage which looks like this

[image]

In my android app I have a webview which shows this webpage. I'm trying to setup a espresso test where I can click on the drop down list and then be able to select, say, the 4th option, Local Users.

There is a "continue" button below the drop down and I have a code

```
onWebView()
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "continueButton"))
        .perform(webClick());
```

to click on the button, but before I do that I need to be able to select the dropdown list and change the selected option. 
Question is how can I do that.

I've tried

```
onWebView()
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "userStoreDomain"))
        .perform(webClick());
```

But then it doesn't even click the drop down list to open it in the first place. Selecting an option is far cry.
Anyone know if its possible with espresso webview?

Comment: do you have any logs from that - to see what happened

Comment: is this problem solved

Comment: @kdas is the problem solved bro? I am also struggling with the same issue!!

Comment: @everyone. The problem is still there.

Comment: Have you tried using Locator.NAME instead of Id? I had this issue with one  of my tests with an element.

Comment: Locator.Name doesn't help. None of the options have that value that I can use to locate.

Comment: Hello, has anyone found a solution to this problem? There is really almost nothing about this problem out there

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution.

this is the solution that is working for me:

```java
onWebView()
    //I use this to allow all needed time to WebView to load
    .withNoTimeout()
    // Find the select element by ID
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "EXPDT_YY"))
    .perform(webClick());
onWebView()
    //I use this to allow all needed time to WebView to load
    .withNoTimeout()
    // I select the element with xpath because I'm using a WebView which I can't control
    //and the <option> elements have only the value attribute
    // I think it should work with any proper Locator (name, id etc..) 
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//option[@value='20']"))
    .perform(webClick());
```